# How to test menu in Android with Robolectric

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, tdd, robolectric

I need to write tests to menu in Android application using Robolectric.

Source code of menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.exit:
        this.finish();
        break;
    default:
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.errMsg), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    }
    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}
```

Please help to write tests

Comment: No one will write tests for you here, so make an attempt on you own and come back with a more elaborate question.

Comment: Hint: TestMenu, TestMenuItem.

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22417800/how-to-test-an-options-menu-items-visibility-in-robolectric

Comment: @Daniel in Robolectric 3.x there are: TestMenu, TestMenuItem

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following example should be a good example for anyone who is getting started with Robolectric. It's using Robolectric 3.0 under AndroidStudio.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 19)
public class MainActivityTest {
    @Test
    public void shouldCloseActivity() {
        MainActivity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);
        MenuItem menuItem = new RoboMenuItem(R.id.exit);
        activity.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
        ShadowActivity shadowActivity = Shadows.shadowOf(activity);
        assertTrue(shadowActivity.isFinishing());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why here we need ShadowActivity? We can just call activity.isFinishing()... Not fully understand.

Answer (score 8):

Actually you should avoid using avoid using RoboMenuItem if possible.  You can get the actual menu created by the activity by having robolectric create the activity and make it visible.

```
MainActivity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().visible().get();
```

You can then use a ShadowActivity to get the actually created menu options;

```
shadowOf(activity).getOptionsMenu()
```

To get the actual MenuItem:

```
shadowOf(activity).getOptionsMenu().findMenuItem(...)
```

You can then pass that actual menuItem into the onOptionsItemSelected.

RoboMenuItem is just a dummy facade and actually it is recommended by the robolectric developers to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Hi, I had something like this - `MainActivity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().start().get();` and if I change `start()` to `visible()`, I get stackoverflow exception. Any idea what could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 4):

kingargyle has a good answer on getting the MenuItem.

If you just want to be able to click on the item however, you can just use:

`shadowOf(activity).clickMenuItem(R.id....);`