# How to test an Options Menu Item's visibility in Robolectric?

Tags: android, robolectric

I would like to assert the visibility of menu items.
However, my menu items always returns true.
I am using the following code to inflate my menu.

```
    SherlockMenuInflater inflater = new SherlockMenuInflater(activity);
    MenuBuilder menu = new MenuBuilder(activity);
    fragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    System.out.println(menu.findItem(R.id.submit).isVisible() + " " + menu.findItem(R.id.next).isVisible() + " "
            + menu.findItem(R.id.done).isVisible());

    assertEquals(3, menu.size());
    assertFalse(menu.findItem(R.id.submit).isVisible());
    assertTrue(menu.findItem(R.id.next).isVisible());
    assertFalse(menu.findItem(R.id.done).isVisible());
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5):

My `OptionsMenu` has two `MenuItem`s, which on of them (`Sort`) has its own `subMenu` with two items.

Here's my `Robolectric` test code for `OptionsMenu` visibility:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21)
public class MainActivityTest {

    private static MainActivity mActivity;

    @Before
    public void setMainActivity() {
        if (mActivity == null) {
            mActivity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().visible().get();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void checkMainActivityOptionsMenuValues() throws Exception {
        //get MainActivity.toolbar instance
        Toolbar toolbar = ButterKnife.findById(mActivity, R.id.toolbar);
        //get ShadowActivity instance
        ShadowActivity shadowActivity = shadowOf(mActivity);
        //call onCreateOptionsMenu using toolbar.menu
        shadowActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(toolbar.getMenu());
        //assert that OptionsMenu has visible items
        assertTrue(shadowActivity.getOptionsMenu().hasVisibleItems());
        //assert that `Settings` MenuItem is visible
        assertEquals(shadowActivity.getOptionsMenu().findItem(R.id.action_settings).isVisible(), true);
        //assert that `Sort` MenuItem is visible
        assertEquals(shadowActivity.getOptionsMenu().getItem(0).getTitle(),
                mActivity.getString(R.string.action_sort));
        //assert that `Sort` has subMenu with `By Value id` value
        assertEquals(shadowActivity.getOptionsMenu().getItem(0).getSubMenu().getItem(0).getTitle(),
                mActivity.getString(R.string.menu_sort_a_z));
        //assert that `Sort` has subMenu with `By Joke Length` value
        assertEquals(shadowActivity.getOptionsMenu().getItem(0).getSubMenu().getItem(1).getTitle(),
                mActivity.getString(R.string.menu_sort_size));
    }
}
```

If you don't use `Butterknife`, instead of line:

```
 Toolbar toolbar = ButterKnife.findById(mActivity, R.id.toolbar);
```

use

```
 Toolbar toolbar = mActivity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

I'm using Robolectric 3.1.

Hope it would help